# MUI Autocomplete dropdown direction

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

Recently I have add mui to my project React.
More particularly I try to use Autocomplete.
But I have problem with the renderer, indeed the dropdown points horizontally and not vertically.
So I have add it like that.

```
<Autocomplete
   disablePortal
   id="combo-box-demo"
   options={["mov1", "mov2", "movie3", "movie4", "movie5"]}
   sx={{ width: 300 }}
   renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
/>
```

But when I run my app, the dropdown points horizontally. But with autocomplete doc https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/, with same code, he points vertically.
[render in my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCj5o.png)
[render doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7PjR.png)

In my package.json I use these version :

```
"@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
"@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.8",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.15",
"@mui/material": "^5.11.0",
```

So I looking for fix that on web, but i didn't find anything. Someone can help me ?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any custom CSS that might be have an effect on the layout?

Comment: Finally, I found that somewhere in my app :
ul {
    display: flex;
}
Very bad idea... So now without that, all working perfectly. Thank for your reply ! You solve my problem

Comment: Awesome! If you don’t mind marking my solution as correct. I love getting those points lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in custom CSS you applied to the ul element.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting

```
disablePortal={true}
```

Your component should look like

```
<Autocomplete
  id="autocomplete-demo"
  options={options}
  disablePortal={true}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField {...params} label="label" variant="outlined" />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: Yes i have try this settings, unfortunately is not working

Comment: So I try with new CRA, with same version, and I don't encounter the problem, so I think it must come from an inherited css properties.